# Python boto3 script to get ec2 instance id and instance name for a list of aws volumes id's

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, volumes

I have bunch of 100 AWS volume id's in a text file.
I want pull those volume id's from text file and get it's attached ec2 instance id and instance name.
Can some one please help with python boto3 code?

Comment: did you tried to write a script? is there any error?

Comment: I was able to script half way and unable to proceed further. Here is the script I wrote. This basically pulls the volumes in file to a list.

import boto3
volumeList = open("volumes.txt", "r")

for i in volumeList:
  print(i)

Comment: Look in the docs for [boto3 ec2 volumes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#volume).  After calling `ec2.Volume('id')`, look at the `attachments` attribute.

Comment: can you please let me know the attachment sample statement? I am bit confused using the attachments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that retrieves the Amazon EC2 Instance ID attached to an Amazon EBS volume:

```py
import boto3

ID = 'vol-08d12e3f3c98c5d17'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

volume = ec2_resource.Volume(ID)

for attachment in volume.attachments:
    print(attachment['InstanceId'])
```

Note that an Amazon EBS volume can be attached to multiple instances, which is why the code iterates through the `attachments` list.

If you want to obtain the 'name' of an Amazon EC2 instance, you would need to call `DescribeInstances` or using `Instance('id')`. Then, look at the Value associated with the `Name` tag.